# como puedo cambiar un numero de mi lista

Tags: c++, lista

Me mandaron hacer un ejercicio de lista enlazada que dice:

> Desarrolle un programa en c++ que cargue una lista de números enteros dados por el usuario y permita reemplazar un valor por otro dado por el usuario.

En el cual ya puedo cargar mi lista con los números que le inserto, mi problema es, ¿Cómo hago para que mi programa me diga que si quiero cambiar unos de los números que inserte, y lo cambie, y salga en la nueva lista?

Aquí les dejo mi código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;

//declarar un nodo
struct NODO {
    int dato;
    struct NODO *sig;
}*cab=NULL;


// inicializar el nodo en cero
void nuevoNODO(){
    struct NODO *aux;
    NODO *nuevo=new NODO ();
    cout<<"ingrese el valor a agregar: "<<endl;
    cin>>nuevo->dato;
    if(cab==NULL)
        cab=nuevo;
    else  
        aux->sig=nuevo;
    aux=nuevo;

}

void mostrar (){
    struct NODO *aux;
    aux=cab;
    while(aux){
        cout<<aux->dato<<"->";
        aux=aux->sig;
    }
}

int main (){

    //cargar los datos

    char r='s';

    while (r=='s'){
        nuevoNODO();
        cout<<"nuevo nodo? (S/N)"<<endl;
        cin >> r;
        r = tolower(r);
    }
    mostrar();
}
```

Comment: Es rara tu tarea. Para cambiar un valor debes seleccionar un nodo, como el usuario va a seleccionar un nodo??? por su índice (lugar en la lista)?, por el valor que tiene el nodo? cual es el criterio?

Comment: @Yussef es por el valor del nodo, según el enunciado: "*permita reemplazar un valor por otro dado por el usuario*".

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que ese programa no funciona. No especificas como crece la lista, parece que es una lista lifo, o sea, que si metes la secuencia de valores
1 2 3
al mostrar te dará
3->2->1->
Sin embargo eso no ocurre (al menos al probar se queda en el primer nodo).
Siguiendo tu lógica la función de agregar nodos sería

```
void nuevoNODO(){
    struct NODO *aux;
    NODO *nuevo=new NODO ();
    cout<<"ingrese el valor a agregar: "<<endl;
    cin>>nuevo->dato;
    nuevo->sig = cab;
    cab = nuevo;
}
```

Insisto, siguiendo la lógica que usas en el código. Creo que una función para agregar nodo debiera hacer solo eso, no pedir el dato. El dato iríia como argumento. Pero siguiendo tu lógica esa modificación hace que el programa funcione.
Y ahora el problema en si, se trata de buscar un nodo determinado y sustituir su valor. Aquí tienes que iterar la lista comparar y sustituir.

```
 void cambiar( int buscar, int nuevo){
    struct NODO *aux; 
    aux=cab;
    while(aux != NULL and aux->dato != buscar ){
        aux=aux->sig;
    }     
    if(aux){
        aux->dato = nuevo;
    }    
 }
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar un dato en una lista, búscalo y cámbialo:

```
NODO *cuatro = busca(4);
cuatro->dato = 42;
```

Pero para que funcione la búsqueda, primero deberías crear la lista correctamente. En tu código no modificas nunca el puntero `cab`, así que la lista nunca crece. Yo he cambiado la función que inserta nodos así:

```
void nuevoNODO()
{
    int dato;
    cout << "ingrese el valor a agregar:\n";
    cin >> dato;

    cab = new NODO{dato, cab ? cab : nullptr};
}
```

Con eso corregido, buscar un nodo es trivial:

```
NODO *busca(int valor)
{
    for (NODO *nodo = cab; nodo; nodo = nodo->sig)
        if (nodo->dato == valor)
            return nodo;

    return nullptr;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVHLbsIwEDxnv2JLDwQoEqX0RUh66bn8QC/GMZGlxI4chx4Q357uxgRFPfZie8femdmxrOulLIUpuu5eG1m2udpp23inRJUBtI02BRpRqaYWUmHj8wSArlvp8Wv/uYczRNp4zIW3CUQM4bzRBaZo2rKsvUvggnMpDmMETlbnVKqT5Y549odG2tbjbocTUneqUahKPInSOhQoCCmE236bCb/UBrPs2kdl0FE/vbkzww/I4Ee/bgcLF3IFENwe2kaKmNV7id7LkaTicG1sbomT2hPkc1hZhbZlRrPOIIr0EeMAsCam6UAWRZFTvnUmNJPHobzFc42j4tiFi/9nYIhsZIKqKU57AZ6uEtqMyBnSxLJKaLtL8ZEOi4VmrtHHsOFgQ7bCO5YNeW1mnH6PDTPjZs3Pb3OMhl2Ri65bwSOs4Qk28Awv8Apv8A6/)</kbd>.

---

Por otro lado, tu código no sigue las buenas prácticas de C++ ni de C++ moderno:

- Incluyes cabeceras innecesarias: No usas ni `<conio.h>` ni `<ctype.h>` y ambas son cabeceras de C, no de C++.
- En C++ las estructuras (`struct`) son tipos, no necesitas anteponer `struct` al nombre de la estructura para crear una instancia.
- No borras con `delete` nada de lo que pides con `new`.
- No encapsulas tus datos.

Si corriges esos problemas, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Lista
{
    ~Lista() { delete cab; }

    void Inserta(int dato)
    {
        cab = new NODO{dato, cab ? cab : nullptr};
    }

    bool Reemplaza(int dato, int nuevo)
    {
        if (NODO *encontrado = busca(dato))
        {
            encontrado->dato = nuevo;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

private:

    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &, const Lista &);

    struct NODO
    {
        ~NODO() { delete sig; }
        int dato;
        NODO *sig = nullptr;
    } *cab = nullptr;

    NODO *busca(int valor)
    {
        for (NODO *nodo = cab; nodo; nodo = nodo->sig)
            if (nodo->dato == valor)
                return nodo;

        return nullptr;
    }
};

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Lista &l)
{
    for (Lista::NODO *nodo = l.cab; nodo; nodo = nodo->sig)
        o << nodo->dato << ' ';

    return o;
}

int main()
{
    Lista l;

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    {
        int dato;
        cout << "ingrese el valor a agregar:\n";
        cin >> dato;
        l.Inserta(dato);
    }

    l.Reemplaza(4, 42);

    cout << l;

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZNNb9swDIbP5q/gOqBN2jRIu@zLTrJLLwOGFeh5F8VmAgGKZEhyBixI/3pGynbj7rJebIqkyJePpLKub0uj7PZ0eq9taZqKFtqF6EntVgBN0HaLVu0o1KokDLEqADjclBF/6BAVHCB7TtZojAesyFAkLNW6wCNAtne6wu82kOcEbSNWKroxZLwr4yRcoqXf@PPx4fEgkYnsxG/pm6NtjKmjPxaQSa21cwafiHa1UX/O1SYolm1o3xfWGxxJSbwmWzobvaocd1o3oVSjJIATU2Z2TrhdSUQESaVCgp5i4y3ytCRr0dD7NsoEanXVXu9VpJyjG6/JVkIpzzuIeOlq8lzZ42Ixeh3haZ0NHUi8HDParGMr8tthnsUcsg16K2x5zA6AaGvH5VAaIGETdXjdQe5d0GW2LKTCXhnnO3AbVtmRsy4xSwcpdvuVUk5YcSdhmFC3npbe8qXemV/aPmA30AfHdJ3ehsv9w8uM5fIlzcmT56@km@l/xDtugQPxvLrCK1HaCWXVfL4Caae0HaV2bW8jWamzRDVXnhX8e7fEOzZubnR/EwdHVLomSo8LflKeAiGZFhYqVOzZKp//shcpVVtcrV52mmn/gtLl7Z6DmZ7fwnyC8/t0f/ouZjDHjOc4nWZwB/fwAebwET7BZ/gCX@Ev)</kbd>.